change detection of variables declared in the extended class in angular 14 applicaiton
I'm looking for the best approach to detect changes in properties declared in extended classes in Angular. These changes are not detected by ngOnChanges because they're not inputs.
I've currently implemented ngDoCheck, which works, but I'm curious if there's a better approach that could potentially improve performance.

You can make observable properties in the class and on the change you can detect. if you don't want to make the observable then you can make the getter and setter of the properties and on the getter and setter function, you can perform any action.
